# How to create Textfield with scroll in AS3 and FlashDevelop?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I am working on a flash game based on an AS3 project using FlashDevelop.
I need a textbox with scroll bar.
I was able to create an editable TextField, but I can't find a way to add
a vertical scroll bar.

Thanks,
SW.

Comment: what flex sdk version are you using to compile your FD project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flash runtime doesn't provide any native UI controls (button, scrollbar, combobox, etc) so you must either use or write components developed in AS3.

Adobe Flash Professional includes a set of UI components; the Flex framework offers many (and heavyweight) components but you must go Flex from the ground up. Both have serious pros and cons but at least their code is interesting to study.

You'll find plenty of (often bad) scrollbar scripts around the web - this is a good exercice to learn Flash.

Please note that you have 2 ways of scrolling text:

- TextFields have a scroll property to scroll text line by line,
- or set a mask (or better a scrollRect) to scroll arbitrary contents including a long TextField.

Answer (score 2):

if you add `flex_sdk_4.1\frameworks\libs\framework.swc` to SWC libraries (at project properties -> compiler options) you may import and use [`mx.controls.VScrollBar`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/VScrollBar.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Comment: Should be noted that that would involve converting the game to exist within the flex framework.

Comment: The game relies on PushButton game engine, i'm not sure it can be converted to be "flex". I have to say that after a decade of developing in C++,C#,Java and XNA I find Flash to be the most confusing, disorganized and messy dev environment I have ever seen.

Comment: Naturally you'd feel this way towards a new platform. I'm going the other way around (AS3 to C#) and I find the windows forms sdk to be incredibly weak and cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to develop one yourself, or find a free solution online. It will generally involved a very high textfield that's revealed only partly due to a mask. The scroll bar then controls the Y position of the textfield, so the mask reveals different parts of the textfield.